# How do I use a .jar file in my project and compile it without an IDE?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I am currently trying to include the jnativehook library and test out one of its examples.

I downloaded the .jar file from its website and created a .java file which has an example program. These are in the same folder.

I have followed other questions on here which have tried to tell me how to compile and run the program. I have tried:

```
javac -classpath jnativehook-2.1.0.jar GlobalKeyListenerExample.java
java -classpath jnativehook-2.1.0.jar GlobalKeyListenerExample
```

It compiles fine, however when I enter the second command to run it I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class GlobalKeyListenerExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GlobalKeyListenerExample
```

All I want to do is be able to include a .jar file in my project and compile it from the command line. I am not using eclipse at the moment because I am getting too many problems with it and I also want to learn to program without IDEs.

(I am on windows by the way). Also, please do not mark this as duplicate. If it was actually a duplicate then I would be able to find a solution to my problem from the other similar questions.

Comment: You need to include the *entire* classpath, not just the jars. Once you specify a classpath manually you must specify *all* of it.

Comment: And the real answer: step back, and learn how to use a build system like gradle or maven. Then you define a **gradle build**, and that can be used within your IDE, and a command line build. For anything you want to do in the real world, running javac yourself is really not appropriate.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had already tried that among many other combinations. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Is that the "real answer" to the specific problem I asked about?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation of javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), especially "Example 3 - Specify a User Class Path" (at the bottom of the page), your java file has to have a package:

```
package com.example;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
  }
}
```

Then that file has to lie in the corresponding directory structure:

```
..something/com/example/GlobalKeyListenerExample.java
```

Now you can call the compiler with

```
javac -classpath jnativehook-2.1.0.jar;...something com/example/GlobalKeyListenerExample.java
```

And after compiling you can start it with

```
java -classpath jnativehook-2.1.0.jar;...something com.example.GlobalKeyListenerExample
```